# Editing SharePoint 2013 Page Layout

Tags: page-layout

we have a custom page layout called HomePage, it has few webpart zone and i need to edit that page and add new web part zone, where should i find the page so i can edited.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Publishing page layouts are stored in [Your Site URL]/_catalogs/masterpage/

The process of adding another web part zone to an existing custom page layout involves a number of steps. Generally speaking:

1. Find the custom page layout HTML file in the masterpage gallery and download it to your machine
2. Open Design Manager and use the Snippet Gallery to generate the code for your new web part zone (alernatively, find an existing web part zone in your HTML page layout, clone it, and give it a unique ID)
3. Insert that code into the HTML layout where you want it to appear in the body section
4. Reupload your HTML page layout source to the masterpage gallery
5. Publish a major version of that HTML file

EDIT: Here is the alternative way, in more detail...

Now that you've located the web part zone code block, copy the entire thing and paste it into a new area of your page layout.

```
                        <div data-name="WebPartZone">
                            <!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
                            <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                            <div xmlns:ie="ie">
                                <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="NEW-ZONE-ID-HERE" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical" Title="NEW ZONE TITLE HERE" PartChromePadding="2px">-->
                                    <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
                                        <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages. -->
                                    <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
                                <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
                            </div>
                            <!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
                        </div>
```

Update the line that says:

```
<!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="NEW-ZONE-ID-HERE" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical" Title="NEW ZONE TITLE HERE" PartChromePadding="2px">-->
```

To include a unique ID (can be anything) and title, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Jake, when i open the page-layout with notepad i can see the ID as like location. Center, Left or right. ID="CenterRightColumn" or ID="CentreColumn", how i can use this ones to create a new one?

Comment: @Harris I will update the answer above

Comment: Hey Jake, appreciated your help